# Bash Automation without asking for password

Tags: command-line, scripts, password

How do I automate this without being ask for password every time it loops?

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for k in 2 3 5 10; do
    sudo ldconfig ########  # password asking here everytime
    python experiments.py 
done
```

Comment: How are your `sudo` privileges defined? `ALL` or only `ldconfig`?

Answer (score 0):

Run your script as sudo: `sudo ./script`